# Which small claims court to use if paid by paypal?

Tags: small-claims-court

I have had a monetary loss in Atlanta but I live in a state far from Georgia. Can I file in small claims court in my state (which would be convenient for me) or do I need to file in Atlanta (which may be prohibitively inconvenient)?  Or does it depend on the rules of the specific small claims courts?

On reflection, perhaps the crime took place over the internet. I paid by paypal and the other party did not use the money as agreed upon, pocketing it instead. So, where did the crime take place?

Answer (score 2):

Why has it come to going court? Paypal themselves should handle it. I've used that route for non-ebay sales several times. Odds are they will refund you, they almost always side with the buyer.

Unless you marked the transfer as "gift", then they won't